# MQ Connect failed with 2195

Tags: queue, ibm-mq, channel

I have WAS MQ 7.1 Server installed in windows. My application running on unix is trying to connect to this server during which it gives the error "MQ Connect failed 2195" in the application logs. On debugging the code , i found it is while connecting to the q manager that it is throwing this error.

I tried to run a netstat on the MQ Server port no. and do a telnet to check if there is any connection being established . But I could not see any connection being established to the q manager .

The possible issues could be 
1. Que Manager has not been started
2. Listener not started
3. Initiation queue not started or created or attached(usually optional depending on set up)
4. Listening to the wrong Port or IP
5. Firewall stopping traffic to Port or IP
6. Queue Manager not created on destination
7. Not authorized to Queue manager and/or channel and/or queue
8. Trial MQ copy expired.
9. Wrong Queue manager name
10. Wrong channel name or password or queue or queue type

Have done the following to check if it is working fine . 
1. Tried to put a message from windows to the MQ Server which was successful. 
2. Gave auth(setmqaut) permission to Request queue that was created. 
3. There is no firewall between application and MQ Server.
4. Channel name , q manager , IP and port no.s are correct.

In my windows MQ Setup i have created the Server connection channel and Client connection Channel.

export the mqm lib to SHLIB_PATH.

Added the application user to mqm group and also the windows user through which I had created the MQ Server setup

Had copied the AMQCLCHL.TAB to the unix machine containing the client program.
exported MQCHLTAB to the table filename
exported MQCHLLIB to the path containing the table name
exported the MQSERVER=QMgrName/CHANNEL1/hostname  from the client machine.

Please let me know if I am missing anything w.r.t connection of the application(in Unix) to the MQ Server(in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

2195 is MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR. It implies something that should not have happened, even if you set it up wrong. It may well be accompanied with an FDC file in the errors directory. You should raise a PMR with IBM Service.